# Select records from table where field not in left join of different table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Struggling to get this at any sensible run time. I have three tables:

temp_company

- id (PRIMARY KEY), number (KEY), s_code (KEY)

company

- id (PRIMARY KEY), number (KEY)

company_scode

- company_id (UNIQUE on company_id and code), code (KEY)
  There is also a foreign key between code and code the code_description table.
  There is also a foreign key between company_id and the id in the company table

I need to match up the temp_company table to the company table on the number field, I then want to check if the s_code in temporary table exists for the company in the company_scode table, if it doesn't then select that row.

So far I have:

```
SELECT temp_company.s_code 
FROM temp_company
WHERE temp_company.s_code NOT IN 
(SELECT code
FROM company
LEFT JOIN company_scode ON company.id = company_scode.company_id
WHERE 
company.number = temp_company.number
)
```

but this is very slow, I would appreciate a better way to select every temp_company record where it's s_code does not exist in the many to many relationship between company and company_scode.

*** UPDATE *****

Thank you to Loc and Ollie for your answers, these are still taking a very long time (I left Ollie's for 8 hours and it was still going).

In terms of index's I have updated above with info. I've put the explains below for the two answers to try to shed some light and hopefully get this faster.

EXPLAIN for Ollie's answer:

```
| id | select_type        | table      | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                   | rows    | extra                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | tc         | ALL   | (NULL)        | (NULL)     | (NULL)  | (NULL)                | 3216320 |                          |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | ALL   | (NULL)        | (NULL)     | (NULL)  | (NULL)                | 2619433 | Using where; Not exists  |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 2  | DERIVED            | s          | index | company_id    | code       | 62      | (NULL)                | 2405379 |              Using index |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 2  | DERIVED            | c          | eq_ref| PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | mydbname.s.company_id |    1    |                          |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN for Loc's answer:

```
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref           | rows    | extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | tc    | ALL   | (NULL)        | (NULL)     | (NULL)  | (NULL)        | 3216320 | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | index | (NULL)        | number     | 63      | (NULL)        | 3189756 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cc    | ref   | company_id    | company_id | 4       | mydbname.c.id |    1    | Using where; Using Index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got this down to a managable time of about 1 minute with the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tc AS
(SELECT company.id AS cid, temp_company.scode AS tcode
FROM temp_company
INNER JOIN company ON temp_company.number = company.number
WHERE temp_company.scode IS NOT NULL AND temp_company.scode != "")

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rc AS
(SELECT tc.cid as cid FROM tc
LEFT JOIN company_scode ON tc.cid = company_scode.company_id
WHERE tc.tcode = company_scode.code)

SELECT * FROM tc
WHERE tc.cid NOT IN (SELECT cid FROM rc)
```

I'd rather not be using temporary tables so if anyone posts a solution in a similar or quicker timeframe then I'll happily update the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

TEST this:

```
SELECT tc.*
FROM temp_company tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM company c LEFT JOIN company_scode cc ON c.id = cc.company_id
    WHERE c.number = tc.number
)
```

Comment: I've updated my above answer with an EXPLAIN for your answer as this is still taking an age to run and would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that might be plenty faster than your nested SELECT.

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.number, tc.s_code
  FROM temp_company AS tc
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT s.code AS company_scode,
             c.id
        FROM company AS c
        JOIN company_scode AS s ON c.id = s.code      
      ) AS existing_company 
           ON  (     tc.scode = existing_company.company_scode
                 AND tc.id = existing_company.id)
  WHERE existing_company.company_scode IS NULL
```

This works by running a subquery that returns a list of (id, scode). It then joins that to the temp_company table and uses IS NULL to look for items that only showed up on the left side of the join.

Comment: I've updated my answer above with an EXPLAIN - your answer was still running after 8 hours. I also had to change your answer to have `AND tc.number = existing_company.number` as the id's don't link these records but the numbers do. That then meant getting `c.number` rather than `c.id`. And there was a typo in `ON c.id = s.code` I think this was meant to be `ON c.id = s.company_id`